# Immediate successor of an element in a linearly orders set

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

In the book of *Algebra* by Hungerford, at page 15, it is asked that

[image]

However, doesn't what is asked to prove contradict with the statement that it follows ?

Moreover, consider $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$, both $1$ and $2$ has no immediate successor, so isn't what is asked to prove wrong ?

Comment: One tip for the future: when you come across a situation like this, the first thing to do is triple check that your proposed counterexample actually satisfies all the conditions of the theorem you're supposed to contradict. In this case, as I pointed out, being well-ordered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do that actually, but sometimes (like when I'm really tired) and I don't even understand what I'm reading, or miss words while reading, so even though there word "well-order" is there, I practically do not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order on $\Bbb R$ is not a well-order since $\Bbb R$ itself is a subset without a minimal element (as is every open interval, by the way). So it is not a counterexample.

The example you are required to provide also does not contradict the statement that you need to prove. If anything, it just means that the linear order you're looking for is *not* a well-order.